Updating latest case number on account, but its not working . Can someone please have a look and correct it
TriggerHelper class:
Public static void CaseIDUpdationOnAccount(List<case> caseList){

    Set<ID> accID=new set<ID>();
    For(Case C:caseList){
        If(c.accountID!=null){
            accID.add(c.AccountID);
        }
    }

    List<Account> acctoUpdate = [SELECT NAME,ID,latest_CaseNumber__c ,(select caseNumber from cases)FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID IN: ACCID];

    For(Account A:acctoUpdate){
        For(Case cas:A.Cases){
            A.latest_CaseNumber__C=cas.CaseNumber;
        }

    }
   If(!acctoUpdate.isEmpty()){
    update acctoUpdate;
   }

    }
}

CaseTrigger:
trigger caseTrigger on Case (before insert) {

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        if(trigger.isBefore){
            caseTriggerHandler.origin_Email(Trigger.new);
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
            caseTriggerHandler.CaseIDUpdationOnAccount(Trigger.new);
        }
    }

}


Case.CaseNumber won't exist until after Insert;

yrillic dry transfers

On your Case trigger, add the after insert, since you are calling the CaseIDUpdationOnAccount on the after insert. Also not sure if this is just a typo but in your method parameters it should be List<Case> caseList.
Also to get the latest case number you need to sort by created date within your child query. And no need to loop through child cases. Just loop through the accounts get the first item of the cases list if it exists and pass that to the account field.

Apex isn't case-sensitive (except for things like sets and the keys of maps), so List<case> caseList and List<Case> caseList are the same (as would be LiSt<CaSe> cAsElIsT). If you already knew that, then the issue is just that the stackexchange platform doesn't render stuff that looks like html for safety reasons (and your answer exhibited that as well, before my edit).

In your trigger you should use after insert event, as you are calling your method CaseIDUpdationOnAccount inside Trigger.isAfter.
trigger caseTrigger on Case (after insert) {

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        if(trigger.isBefore){
            caseTriggerHandler.origin_Email(Trigger.new);
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
            caseTriggerHandler.CaseIDUpdationOnAccount(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}

Also, you need to modify your helper a little bit with below query and you do not need to assign the the case id again and again in account, only first item should work.
SELECT NAME,ID,latest_CaseNumber__c ,(select caseNumber from cases order by createdDate desc )FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID IN: ACCID

accounts is the account ids from Case trigger.new.
Try below code using map:
    Map<Id, String> accountCaseNumbers = new Map<Id, String>();
    List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, AccountId 
                            FROM Case 
                            WHERE AccountId IN :accounts 
                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
        
    for (Case c : cases) {
        if (!accountCaseNumbers.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
            accountCaseNumbers.put(c.AccountId, c.CaseNumber);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for (Account acc : accounts) {
        if (accountCaseNumbers.containsKey(acc.Id)) {
            acc.Latest_Case_Number__c = accountCaseNumbers.get(acc.Id);
            accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
    }


simply swapping before insert for after insert as you have would help solve this issue, but would introduce another issue (given that other code is intended to be called on before insert).
